# MapQuest Open Data API routing, start and finish same place

Tags: openstreetmap, mapquest

First of all, I love this free API and the benefits are endless! I have used it to plan trips from my house, to lots of other points, in the best way possible. Using the optimised route, can I then with this API get it to calculate the best route, finishing at the same place where the route started from?.

Is this possible with their API?

Comment: Of course it is possible to specify the same start and end point. Is your question about calculating the shortest route between all via points, i.e. the [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)?

Comment: Yes, I am using the optimised route for this. So I start at one location and it plots a perfect route, ideally I would then like it to return to the last point. (and include the return point in the journey plan optimisation, e.g not just plot a route back from last point to the start point, but work out the best circular route). I have done this with the google api, as you have start point, end point and then waypoints. But I cannot see how to do this with the MapQuest API.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the [most routing services](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/OnlineRouters) support 'circuits' only if you specify a via point at the outer limit.

There is https://www.komoot.de that allows you to generate a parcours for certain params (e.g. running for an hour with intermediate height shifts)